# Recursive solution?

Tags: python, python-3.x

QUESTION: we've got 3 kind of coins($1,$2,$5) and we are going to have a mixture of these coins in order to make $1000 ; we want 
the number of all possible ways of creating $1000 using these coins and also we need to print each possible way

I've just write the below code for the question of coins in a non-recursive style and it is working properly.
now I need to wite a recursive function that do the same thing but I just can't figure out
 the base case of my recursive function.any ideas for writing a recursive function?

```
i=0
for x in range(1001):
  for y in range(501):
    for z in range(201):
        if x + 2*y + 5*z == 1000:
            print(" {} coin $1 , {} coin $2 , {} coin $5".format(x,y,z))
            i+=1
print("number of possibilities",i)
```

Comment: On each recursion you subtract the value of the coin you're adding to the mixture from the total you need to produce. The base case is when the total is 0.

Comment: You don't need the `z` loop for the non-recursive solution. Calculate `zz = 1000-(x+2*y)` and check whether `zz` is divisible by 5. If so, you have a solution with `z = zz/5`.

Comment: BTW - the recursive solution will benefit from memoization, or you could use a tabular/dynamic programming alternative - either way to improve the performance by not considering different ways to achieve the same coin-counts - obviously if you select a $1 then a $2, that's equivalent to selecting a $2 then a $1. If you don't know about memoization or dynamic programming, though, don't worry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really doubt whether recursive is a best approach for doing this. Dynamic programming will always suit best for this kind of tasks. Here is a recursive code.

```
def counts(x, y, z):
    if(x + y + z > 1000):
        return

    if x + y + z == 1000:
        print(" {} coin $1 , {} coin $2 , {} coin $5".format(x,y/2,z/5))

    counts(x+1, y, z)
    counts(x, y+2, z)
    counts(x, y, z+5)


counts(1, 2, 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have three base cases:

- If the total amount of money to create equals to 0 you have only one way to create this sum.
- If total amount money to create is less than 0, there is no way to create the sum - so there're 0 ways.
- If there're 0 kinds of coins, you can't make any sum from them, so there're 0 ways.

If you need an in-depth explanation of recursive approach of solving this problem, you can read it in "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs" (I've read it in my native language, so I can't point you to the exact page - it has to be somewhere in section named like "Recursion").

Answer (score 1):

aga has already listed base cases, but referred to SICP for how to do the recursion (reputedly an excellent book - I haven't read it though I'll warn you I *do* know it targets Scheme - a Lisp dialect).

Basically, what you need to do for each recursive step is...

1. Check whether you've reached a base case. If so, determine whether you've found a valid solution or not, and output a solution if needed. Either way, return (backtrack) to find more solutions.
2. Otherwise, choose each possible coin type in turn, updating totals and making the recursive call for each.

The totals you'd pass for each call *must* include the count for each coin value, and may also include the total value so far (though you could equally calculate that whenever you need it).

Pseudocode...

```
def recursive_solution (totals) :
  if found_a_base_case :
    if its_a_valid_solution_base_case :
      output solution
  else
    derive totals for adding another $5
    recursive_solution (those_new_totals)

    derive totals for adding another $2
    recursive_solution (those_new_totals)

    derive totals for adding another $1
    recursive_solution (those_new_totals)
```

As I mentioned in the comments, this will do lots of redundant work - one side-effect is that it will tend to find each solution multiple times. To prevent that, you need to remember which solutions you've already found. If you also remember partial solutions you've already tried and use that to avoid re-doing that work, that's called memoization.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution. But it will generate duplicate solutions. Dynamic programming would still be better to  solve the problem.

```
>>> def coins(total, coins1=0, coins2=0, coins5=0):
...     if total == 0:
...             print "%s 1$, %s 2$, %s 5$" % (coins1, coins2, coins5)
...             return
...     if total < 0:
...             return
...     coins(total - 1, coins1 + 1, coins2, coins5)
...     coins(total - 2, coins1, coins2 + 1, coins5)
...     coins(total - 5, coins1, coins2, coins5 + 1)
...
>>> coins(1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def changes(amount, coins):
    possibilities = [0] * (amount + 1)
    possibilities[0] = 1
    for coin in coins:
        for j in range(coin, amount + 1):
            possibilities[j] += possibilities[j - coin]
    return possibilities[amount]

print(changes(1000, [1,2,5]))
#50401
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive and dynamic way. Take your pick:

```
def dynamic(tgt,coins):
    combos = [1]+[0]*tgt
    for coin in coins:
        for i in range(coin, tgt+1):
            combos[i] += combos[i-coin]
    return combos[tgt]         

def recursive(tgt,coins):
    if coins==[1]: return 1
    coin = coins.pop()
    return sum(recursive(tgt%coin + coin*n, coins[:]) for n in range(tgt//coin+1)) 

print(dynamic(1000,[1,2,5])) 
# 50401
print(recursive(1000,[1,2,5]))  
# 50401
```